# Why I get error with request to Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: php, google-identity-toolkit

I work with restAPI Identity Toolkit.

I get good response with request

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode
```

but there is a parameter 'returnOobLink' by default it's false.
When I set it true to get OobCode for building my own custom request, I get error

```
{error:
    code: 400,
    message: 'INNSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION'
}
```

Which permission needs?

Comment: Only mention of OobCode on https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/access-control is for method `GetOobCode`, and the required permission would be `firebaseauth.users.sendEmail`.